# Measured GFLOPS is greater then theoretical GFLOPS

Tags: octave

I have written a script to measure the GFLOPS that I can expect for an element-wise matrix multiplication in Octave. My CPU is a i7-2670QM @ 2.2GHz. Looking at the [spec](http://download.intel.com/support/processors/corei7/sb/core_i7-2600_m.pdf) the theoretical GFLOPS is 70.4. Running the script below which uses just one of the four cores of my system I measured 185 GFLOPS.

```
1;

n = 4096;
x = rand(n, n);
tic, x = x .* x;
y = toc
printf('GFLOPS: %f\n', n * n / y / 1e6);
```

Starting Ocatve and running the script (mult.m):

```
octave:1> mult
y =  0.090080
GFLOPS: 186.247910
```

The script performs 4096 * 4096 double precision multiplications (FLOPS) in 0.09 seconds, i.e. 186 GFLOPS. This is much greater then the theoretical 70.4 GFLOPS. What is wrong?

The operator .* is an element-wise multiplication as you can see:

```
octave:1> a = [1, 2; 3, 4];
octave:2> b = [2, 3; 4, 5];
octave:3> a .* b
ans =

    2    6
   12   20
```

Thus, I expect n² multiplications.

Comment: Matrix multiplies are O(N^3) work, not O(N^2), for the classic naive implementation.  MATLAB probably uses a sophisticated implementation of matrix multiply (Strassen?) whose complexity is more than O(N^2) and less than O(N^3); the actual number will be implementation dependent.

Comment: The operator .* is an element-wise matrix multiplication. So O(n²) multiplications should be performed. (I have updated my question with an example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are measuring M(ega)FLOPS (1e6), not G(iga)FLOPS (1e9)

Comment: And he isn't measuring the FPU, he is measuring memory bandwidth. Reading and writing 128 MB of memory.

Comment: For practical applications memory is almost always involved. I just wanted to see how good Octave utilizes the CPU for a operation that is common in practice not the (theoretical) performance of the FPU.